# Is there any work around for using PATCH method in scribe

Tags: scribe

[Scribe PATCH request not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21119913/scribe-patch-request-not-working)

i have gone through the jersey guys workaround but i was not certain how i can use that in my logic as per there work around we need java.net.HttpURLConnection object but this was private member of request class in scribe Below logic i was trying to implement

```
OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.PATCH,url);
Service.signRequest(konyAccessToken, request);//service is OAuthService instance
String result = response.getBody();
```

Currently i am getting error as PATCH was not supported by scribe(as it uses HttpURLConnection) how can i achieve this using above work around (or any other workaround)

Thanks in advance Surya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It take me while to figure it out but finally got solution we can override the HTTP Method
  using "x-http-method-override" header parameter here is the sample code for that

```
OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST,url);
request.addHeader("x-http-method-override", "PATCH");  
Service.signRequest(konyAccessToken, request);//service is OAuthService instance      
String result = response.getBody();
```

this work for other HTTP Methods like DELETE,TRACE....